# How can I set fixed height and width in percentage (dispaly: flex)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Want to create 2 columns and many rows of rectangles. Did this but then I want to make responsive grid, change width and height to, e.g., 40 and 20 percent and then everything gone wrong. How can I set fixed width and height in percentage, not px, to make responsive grid?

Is it possible to do this without `display:table` and only flex or not?

And one more question. Will this grid be responsive, if perspective equal 600px?
Thank you

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.01rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    color: #3A4145;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'kern' 1;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: 'kern' 1;
    -o-font-feature-settings: 'kern' 1;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    }

    .container {
      width: 40%;
      height: 40%;
      margin: 0 auto 60px;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-perspective: 600px;
         -moz-perspective: 600px;
           -o-perspective: 600px;
              perspective: 600px;
    }

    .container ul {
      width: 500px;
      height: 650px;
      opacity: 0.7;
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: wrap;
      align-content: stretch;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px,0px,1px);
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px,0px,1px);
           -o-transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px,0px,1px);
              transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px,0px,1px);
    }

    .container li {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      width: 50%;
      height: 20%;
      color: white;
      background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid white;
      transition: transform .33s, box-shadow .33s;

    }

    .container ul li a {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
      padding-left: 3%;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox rectangles</h1>
  <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>Test</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>

      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: simply change the px to %

Comment: And then width will be 600px, because of width of `.container`, but height will become like 1 line of text.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this you want ??**

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
 letter-spacing: 0.01rem;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 line-height: 1.75em;
 color: #3A4145;
 -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'kern' 1;
 -moz-font-feature-settings: 'kern' 1;
 -o-font-feature-settings: 'kern' 1;
 text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
}
.container {
 width: 40%;
 min-width: 320px;
 height: 40%;
 margin: 0 auto 60px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-perspective: 600px;
 -moz-perspective: 600px;
 -o-perspective: 600px;
 perspective: 600px;
}
.container ul {
 width: 100%;
 height: 650px;
 opacity: 0.7;
 color: white;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: wrap;
 align-content: stretch;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
 -moz-transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
 -o-transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
 transform: rotateY( 5deg ) translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
}
.container li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 width: 50%;
 height: 20%;
 color: white;
 background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 1px solid white;
 transition: transform .33s, box-shadow .33s;
}
.container ul li a {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
 padding-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>Test</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>One</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Practically. I want to set `width` and `height` in `.container ul` in `%`. And the shape will be rectangle, not square or something.

Comment: @AlexanderFrolov , You can change both values `width and height`.

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong, but I get this: https://jsfiddle.net/n3moxckL/

But I want aspect ratio like in original post.

Comment: You said `I want to set width and height in .container ul in %` , you can set the `width` in `%`. But you can set the `height` in `%` .

The `height of ul` depent on it's `content`.

If you want to know this `try to change height` in your above link.
@AlexanderFrolov